# Format a row based on partial matches from a list

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, lookup

I have an Excel workbook with four sheets. Sheet 1 has a list of names (text) row 1-150 and sheets 2, 3 and 4 are large spreadsheets with many columns.

I need a formula that:

- Uses the 150 name range in column A, and looks up the first 4 characters i.e. `LEFT(A1,4*)` to include a wildcard.
- It then uses this to find partial matches in sheet 2, 3 and 4 (which could be in any cell).
- When a partial match is found, it formats the row to a designated colour (let's say yellow)
- It then checks/formats all rows in all sheets.

Comment: What have you tried - please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of FIND, syntax:

```
=FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])
```

Use this to find a spesific part of the name strings, I.e

```
=IF(FIND(LEFT(A1,4),A1)=TRUE,1,0)
```

If i understood your OP correctly, this should solve your issue. The IF parts helps you return a boolean result, which makes it easy to apply conditional formatting. The example above would be inserted into a column to the right of your name column..

For the next time though, you should show what you've tried and post your code. This is not a free code forum.. Best regards.

Comment: I appreciate your informing me this is not a free code forum.

Comment: I have made good use of your indicated code solution and worked on it a little.  =IF(ISERROR(FIND(LEFT(A$118,4),"Sheet1!")), 1, 0)  So here I have attempted to allow that the text its searching for may be in a different case hence ISERROR, Sheet1 I hoped would indicate all of sheet one without entering a range.  Currently I get a 1 (true) result even though there is no matching text on the other sheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Great to hear! Nice work with working around possible different cases

Comment: Moving on from my last I now have this; =IF(ISERROR(FIND(LEFT(A118,4),Sheet1!$A$2:$BW$97)), 1, 0)   Sadly all results are 1, whether there is an actual presence of the search criteria or not. Grr.  As there is more than one name in the search source, it would be ideal to search the first four characters of each word (until all words have been searched). Then return which four characters matched and in which sheet the match was made.  Out of my league